# Write a delimited string to worksheet table Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a small VBA macro to update an Excel sheet. The data comes from a server, and I retrieve it through a SOAP request. However, the server replies to me in this format:

```
rows_number|columns_number|label_1|label_2|label_3|data_1_1|data_1_2|data_1_3|data_2_1|data_2_2|data_3
```

So it's basically a long string delimited by "|", with the first 2 elements being a sort of header with the indication of the number of columns and rows, and the rest is data. I want to transform this string into a table I can write to the Excel worksheet, like suppose I have a string:

3|3|X|Y|Z|a|b|c|d|e|f

I want to write this to an Excel sheet as:

[image: Example]

Is there an easy/fast way of doing this in VBA? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim test As String
test = "3|3|X|Y|Z|a|b|c|d|e|f"
Dim arr As Variant 
arr = Split(test, "|")  'First we need to make an array of items split by "|"

Dim column  As Integer
Dim row     As Integer
Dim nextRow As Integer
Dim i       As Integer

column = 1
row = 1

nextRow = CInt(arr(0)) 'We need this number to know when we should change the row
For i = 2 To UBound(arr) 'We are starting from index 2 - to avoid 2 first items in the array
    ws.Cells(row, column) = arr(i)
    column = column + 1
    If column > nextRow Then
        column = 1
        row = row + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Works great! Although I miss list comprehensions from Python ;) thank you!